# Access Easticsearch from my local IP

Tags: networking, elasticsearch, ip, localhost, host

I have an Elasticsearch running on localhost, but how can I access it using my local IP?

So instead of `127.0.0.1:9200` I want to access it through `192.168.1.3:9200` from my local network.

I have tried setting `network.host: 192.168.1.3` in elasticsearch.yml but I’ve read that this is not necessary.

**Clarification:**

I can do a curl and get a 200 response to my local IP, but the results are always empty.

Comment: What OS?  You shouldn't have to do anything special to make it bind to all addresses, so that probably means you are running into a firewall/SELinux setting that's preventing you from accessing it remotely.

Comment: @Alcanzar OSX, but please see my clarification

Comment: Have you tried `curl -D - http://192.168.1.3/_search` to see if you are getting a redirect or something weird like that?  It may be that your router/default route/something is set weird and its getting intercepted by your router (the `-D -` dumps the header of the response to stdout)